# Changing the header of the exported latex

Tags: latex, org-mode

The standard header of the latex file exported from org is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
etc.
```

My `.org` file contains text in Hebrew. To make that work with latex, I need to modify the header as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
% BEGIN for Hebrew support
\makeatletter
\let\l@hebrew\l@nohyphenation
\makeatother
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, hebrew]{babel}
% END for Hebrew support
% DISABLED \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% DISABLED \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
etc.
```

I tried beginning my org file like this:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \makeatletter
#+LATEX_HEADER: \let\l@hebrew\l@nohyphenation
#+LATEX_HEADER: \makeatother    
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{ucs}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
```

However, this inserts the lines much later in the header than needed. Also, it does not take care of removing the lines that need to be removed to avoid conflicts.

Is it possible to do what I need?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Org, but saw [this](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/examples/article-class.html). Perhaps you can load the document with `[NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]` and then load what you want?

Comment: @Werner Great hint! Thanks!